# Castalia WBAN application | Getting Throughput

Tags: omnet++

I want to get a comparison between the throughput for bybassrouting and Multiringrouting for WBAN network based on BaselineMAC and then draw a plot for comparison.

I have added the following in the .ini file

```
[General]

include ../Parameters/Castalia.ini

sim-time-limit = 100s

#include ../Parameters/SensorDevice/Accelerometer.ini

#SN.physicalProcessName = "CarsPhysicalProcess"
#SN.physicalProcess[*].car_interarrival = 5 #every 5 mins a car will move


SN.wirelessChannel.pathLossMapFile = "../Parameters/WirelessChannel/BANmodels/pathLossMap.txt"
SN.wirelessChannel.temporalModelParametersFile = "../Parameters/WirelessChannel/BANmodels/TemporalModel.txt"

SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.RadioParametersFile = "../Parameters/Radio/BANRadio.txt"
SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.symbolsForRSSI = 16
SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.TxOutputPower = "-15dBm"


#------------------------------------------------------------------
SN.node[*].ApplicationName = "BridgeTest"
SN.node[*].Application.collectTraceInfo = true
SN.node[0].Application.isSink = true
SN.node[*].Application.startupDelay = 1     #wait for 1sec before starting sending packets
SN.node[0].Application.latencyHistogramMax = 600
SN.node[0].Application.latencyHistogramBuckets = 30
SN.node[3].Application.packet_rate = 5
SN.field_x = 100
SN.field_y = 20
SN.deployment = "[0]->center;[1..18]->6x3"
SN.numNodes = 19
#------------------------------------------------------------------
SN.physicalProcess[0].point1_x_coord = 0
SN.physicalProcess[0].point1_y_coord = 10
SN.physicalProcess[0].point2_x_coord = 100
SN.physicalProcess[0].point2_y_coord = 10
#------------------------------------------------------------------


#------------------------------------------------------------------
SN.node[*].Communication.MACProtocolName = "BaselineBANMac"
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.phyDataRate = 1024
SN.node[0].Communication.MAC.isHub = true
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.macBufferSize = 48
#------------------------------------------------------------------

[Config myRouting]
SN.node[*].Communication.RoutingProtocolName = "MultipathRingsRouting"
SN.node[*].Application.reportDestination = "0"

[Config noRouting]
SN.node[*].Communication.RoutingProtocolName = "BypassRouting"
SN.node[*].Application.reportDestination = "0"
```

I don't know how can I have the throughput for these routing.

this application (BridgeTest) contains the output named  Reprogram reception 
[Application output for BridgeTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5X1n.png)

Please help me with the command to have the throughput test comparison.
Note: 
I tried using 
`SN.node[*].ApplicationName = "ThroughputTest"` and it gave me an error as it is not defining isSink Variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be good to be clear and precise about what you want to measure and for what purpose. Do you have a real problem or is this just part of your learning experience with Castalia? I am asking because "measuring the throughput of different routing protocols" is a rather vague statement, especially when one of the protocols is BypassRouting which means no routing! I'll assume here that this is part of your learning journey with Castalia and you are simply playing around with the simulator, but please do update your question if other assumptions are important.

Looking at the ini file I can see that you've missed several important facts:

- You are trying to use routing (MultiPathRings) with BaselineBANMAc.
  BaselineBANMAc only supports communication between the hub and the
  children nodes. Children nodes **cannot communicate with each
  other**. So BaselineBANMAc is to be used with star network topologies
  only. There are no multiple hops. Of course you can use another MAC
  that allows communication between all nodes. For example TMAC or
  TunableMAC.
- The BridgeTest application does some sort of app-level routing (basically rebroadcasting packets it receives based on some simple rules). So it is NOT a good application to test with a routing module. You should read the manual (section 3.6.2) and inspect the code of the BridgeTest application to get a better understanding of its functionality.
- The BridgeTest application uses two kinds of packets: 1) Report packets (basically sensing data) that flow from the 18 sensing nodes to the sink node and 2) Reprogram packets that flow from the sink nodes to the sensing nodes. These have different characteristics (the frequency they get create and the volume of data created)
- You have commented out the physical process lines, basically having no physical process. This means that there is nothing to sense so there will be no reporting packets from the sensing nodes to the sink nodes (the first kind of packets I mentioned above). Not sure if this is intentional.

I suggest you revisit what you want to achieve and what is the exact simulation scenario you want to test (beyond the vague statement you wrote at the beginning of your question). Study the different parts/modules that you think are relevant to achieve your goal, and you are welcome to ask more questions here.